# Totally ordered sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, order-theory

Let T be a totally ordered set that is **finite**. Does it follow that minimum and maximum of T exist? 
Since T is finite, I believe there exists a minimal of T. From that it maybe able to be shown that the minimal is the minimum but not quite sure whether it is the right approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Claim:** A totally ordered set with at least one *minimal* element has a *minimum* element.

**Proof sketch:** Let $b$ be the minimal element.  If $b$ were not in fact the minimum, then by definition of minimum, "$b \le a$ for all $a$" would be false.  Pick some $a$ for which $b \le a$ is not true, and derive a contradiction using totality.

Comment: Let m be a minimal of T. Let x∊T and m∊T. Then m≤x or x≤m. by definition of minimal then x=m or m≤x. This implies m≤x. Thus m is the minimum. Is this right ?

Comment: Yes, as Cameron has noted, this is correct.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, so long as $T$ is nonempty. Since $T$ is totally ordered, then minimal is equivalent to minimum (one direction is easy, the other follows by totality/comparability). Similarly for maximal and maximum.

Comment: Can any one suggest a formal proof?

Comment: Minimum immediately implies minimal by definition. In a total order, use comparability (and the definitions of minimal, minimum) to see that minimal implies minimum.

Comment: Let m be a minimal of T. Let x∊T and m∊T. Then m≤x or x≤m. by definition of minimal then x=m or m≤x. This implies m≤x. Thus m is the minimum. Is this right ?

Comment: Bingo! (Although you don't have to mention that $m\in T$ in the second sentence, since you've already assumed that $m$ is a minimal element of $T$.)

Comment: Noted! Thanks alot

Comment: No problem. Just so you're aware, if somebody gives a good answer to a question (whether yours or somebody else's), you can "upvote" it (click the up arrow on the left side of the answer), and if someone's answer to one of your questions is what you want, you can "accept" it (click on the check mark on the left side of their post). Be aware that you can only accept one answer, but you can upvote up to (I think) 40 posts (including other people's questions) per day. Welcome to math.SE!

Answer (score 0):

If a totally ordered set is finite **and nonempty**, then it follows that it has a maximum and a minimum.

Answer (score 0):

By induction, you can show that any linearly ordered set $T$ of cardinality $n>0$ has a minimum and a maximum.

If $n=1$, $T=\{p\}$ and $p$ is the minimum and the maximum of $T$. Then, if $\text{card}(T)=n+1$ take a subset of cardinality $n$ ant its minimum $m$ and its maximum $M$. If $p$ is the last element in $T$, just distinguish the cases $p<m$, $p>M$ and $m<p<M$.